# How to use Reduce to solve matrix/vector equation

Tags: equation-solving, system

Suppose $A$ is an $2 \times 2$ matrix of unknowns, and $x$ is an $2 \times 1$ vector of unknowns. How can I use $A$ and $x$ as variables to be solved for in Reduce or FindInstance?

example given a vector $b$. I want to do something like

```
Reduce[A*x == {{1},{1}}, x*b== 1, {x}]
```

Comment: Could you please give an example of what you mean by a `matrix of unknowns`? `LinearSolve[{{a, b}, {c, d}}, {x, y}]` ?

Comment: @Syed Rather than having an unknown scalar x of size 1 by 1, I want the unknown to be a matrix of size n by n.

Comment: Should `Ax` be the product of `A` and `x`? You need a space or `*`, or a `.` between them then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not think that Mathematica can solve for matrices or vectors. But writing out your problem componentwise one gets a system of three equation for 6 unknowns (components of $A$ and $x$ if one assumes $b$ is given?) which can be used to eliminate 3 unknowns. This code sets up the equation system `eqs`:

```
aMatrix=Table[a[i,j],{i,1,2},{j,1,2}]
bVector=Table[b[j],{j,1,2}]
xVector=Table[x[j],{j,1,2}]

{aMatrix.xVector=={1,1},xVector.bVector==1}

eqs=Flatten[%/.Equal[x_List,y_List]:>MapThread[Equal,{x,y}]/;Length[x]===Length[y]]
```

which can be solved for *e.g.* `a11`, `a22` and `x1`:

```
Solve[eqs, {a[1, 1], a[2, 2], x[1]}]
```

resulting in

> `{{a[1, 1] -> (b[1] (-1 + a[1, 2] x[2]))/(-1 + b[2] x[2]),  a[2, 2] -> (-a[2, 1] + b[1] + a[2, 1] b[2] x[2])/(b[1] x[2]),  x[1] -> (1 - b[2] x[2])/b[1]}}`

After specifying an explicit $b$ *e.g.* `b={1,1}` one can use `FindInstance` with the equation system to find a solution instance:

```
FindInstance[eqs/.{b[1]->1,b[2]->1},{a[1,1],a[1,2],a[2,1],a[2,2],x[1],x[2]}]
```

resulting in

> `{{a[1,1]->1,a[1,2]->1,a[2,1]->-3,a[2,2]->-1,x[1]->-1,x[2]->2}}`

Does this help?

Comment: Your definitions would be more succinct using `Array`, i.e., `aMatrix = Array[a, {2, 2}]; bVector = Array[b, 2]; xVector = Array[x, 2];`

Comment: @N0Va Thanks! What does eqs=Flatten[%/.Equal[x_List,y_List]:>MapThread[Equal,{x,y}]/;Length[x]===Length[y]] do?

Comment: @Morcus It flattens out the equation list where the rule splits identities for list into identities for the list components e.g.: `{a,b}=={c,d}` goes to `{a==c,b==d}`.